# Apache / Load balancing behavior with status=+H

Tags: apache

I have the following in `proxy.conf`:

```
ProxyPass "/doc/b" "balancer://mycluster"
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5006/doc route=node1
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5008/doc route=node2 status=+H
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    ProxySet stickysession=uuid
</Proxy>

ProxyPass "/doc/a" "balancer://mycluste1"
<Proxy "balancer://mycluste1">
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5006/doc route=node1 status=+H
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5008/doc route=node2
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    ProxySet stickysession=uuid
</Proxy>
```

When the apache get `/doc/b` requests, everything works fine and all the request go to port `5006` .

But when the apache get `/doc/a` requests, 50% of the requests go to `5006`, and 50% of the requests go to `5008`.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You use the same uuid for both balancers.

> ProxySet stickysession=uuid

So they are overwriting each other